# Should library be using androidx or android.support?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, android-jetpack

I am building a third party library, I am trying to release the library that depends on AndroidX and implementing it into a customer's app project that still depends on android.support.

The only solution I can think of at the moment is having two branches with two library versions.

One that uses Support in my library the other is using Android X. However this will might be hard to maintain in the near future as bug fixes or new features will mean it needs to be updated on both sides. There does not seem to be another way.

Is there anyway my customers can use my Android X library while still on support?

Comment: Simple answer is **NO**, for one project it can only choose either the android.support libraries or androidx libraries, they are exclusive!

Comment: @shizhen that's not 100% accurate you can use Android X with support library via Jetifier which will convert Android support to Android X.

Comment: Jetifier is more like a temporary solution for the case that user wants to make both libraries coexist, personally I don't think this is a "clean" solution for library dependencies management.

Comment: The app might complaint about the widgets or components you use in library. You can't use same components though. The solutions here is you create library to support android.support components & other one is create a support for androidx components.

Comment: I think in the near future android team will drop support for support packages .androidX replacing the android.support.So better to maintain androidX only and communicate the app team to switch from android.support to androidX

Comment: yes i agree @SIVAKUMAR.J, similar to how they deprecated GCM for Firebase. Thanks heaps for help.

Answer (score 0):

"**Note: With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called AndroidX which is part of Jetpack. The AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also includes the latest Jetpack components. 
You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as android.support.*) will remain available on Google Maven. However, all new library development will occur in the AndroidX library. 
We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well.**"

the above statement provided by [android developers official site](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup)
Hence the new updates are added only in androidx and not in android.support